# PHP fetching (Replace TEXT with PICTURE) Need to make it work in IE, Opera and Mozilla

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my code of displaying text from database and replace it with pictures:

```
echo"<div><table>";
$role = "SELECT vidRoles FROM videoinformation WHERE id=".$row['id'];
if ($result2 = mysqli_query($con, $role)) {
    while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_row($result2)) {
        $values = explode(',',$row3[0]);
        foreach($values as $v2)
        if (!empty($v2)) {
           printf ("<img src=\"addVid/roles/%s.jpg\" class=\"roleImg img-circle\" >", $v2);
        }
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result2);
}
else{
    echo $lang['vldErrorMaRo'];
}
echo "</table></div></div></div>";
```

No problem with the code everything working fine, (Style, functionality) **BUT** this working ONLY in Chrome, and do not working in Mozilla, Opera, IE10... 

Problem is that in other browsers PICTURES do not show up.

Comment: Probably missing a chunk of code but some extra `</div>`'s there. Server-side processing has no effect on what browser you are using? It's advised for many reasons to use the full path to the image as well e.g `http://www.example.com/addVid/roles/%s.jpg` and alt attribute as both play a large part in accurate SEO

Comment: Everything displayed nicely, BUT the only thing what is not working is the actual pictures are not show up.

Comment: @Zanderwar full path doesn't make any difference....

Comment: [Pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com) the source of the output you receive. Your issue is client-side only at the moment after fixing the previous. (Generally Right Click > View Source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add `<tbody>` `<tr>` and `<td>` tags

```
echo "<div><table><tbody>";
$role = "SELECT vidRoles FROM videoinformation WHERE id=".$row['id'];
if ($result2 = mysqli_query($con, $role)) {
    while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_row($result2)) {
        $values = explode(',',$row3[0]);
        foreach($values as $v2)
        if (!empty($v2)) {
           printf ("<tr><td><img src=\"%s.jpg\" class=\"roleImg img-circle\" alt=\"%s.jpg\"></td></tr>", $v2, $v2);
        }
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result2);
}
else{
    echo $lang['vldErrorMaRo'];
}
echo "</tbody></table></div></div></div>";
```

And don't forget alt attr in images

Comment: the point is, (I don't forget about alt...and so on)..using your answer code displays not correctly... as well when I put something in alt...code not working correctly as well... BUT when I put same code without php...just plain HTML everything is nice and working...

Comment: I mean <tbody><tr><td> tags.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, change this line to this printf ("<tr><td><img src=\"%s.jpg\" class=\"roleImg img-circle\" alt=\"%s.jpg\"></td></tr>", $v2, $v2);

Comment: Ok, I don't know what return from your DB. I just set this code here http://78.47.130.163/pu/, and all works well

Comment: this is in dev mode...  <img class="roleImg img-circle" alt="addVid/roles/Name2.jpg" src="http://WEBSITE.net/addVid/roles/Name2.jpg"> Looks okay, do not knwo why it's not working.